# Memory Leak about for each instance

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, instance

Sorry,I'm beginner.
I don't know how to fix my memory leak.
I use instrument to check leak.
And I find that I create city model instance, and what should I Recycling memory.
What should I do to fix it?
Thanks.

```
class CityList:DefaultModel {

    func getCities() {
    let query = mainDB.city
    do {
        let results = try mainDB.db?.prepare(query)
        results?.forEach({ (row) in
            let cityId = row[Schema.cityId.TEXT]
            if cityId.isEmpty == false {
                if let city = self.cities[cityId] {
                    city.fromQueryRow(row)
                } else {
                    let city = City(cityId) //memory leak
                    city.fromQueryRow(row)  //memory leak
                    self.cities[cityId] = city
                }
            }
        })
        self.notifySubject.onNext("")
    } catch {
        debug(object: error)
    }

}

}
```

```
class City:NSObject {

let notifySubject = PublishSubject<Any>()

var id:String = ""
@objc var name:String = ""
var userId:String = ""
var country:String = ""
var descriptions:String = ""


override init() {
    super.init()
}

init(_ id:String) {
    super.init()
    self.id = id
}
}
```

Comment: Please show code for City?

Comment: City is a model .I updated.

Comment: Please show complete code for CityList and please show the screenshot of instruments where memory leak is recognized